# Customized twitter share button

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I customise a twitter share button after generating the twitter button share code.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=Stridalyzer&text=visit%20us%20%40add ur url" class="twitter-mention-button" data-size="large">Tweet to </a>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I took a look and I would either except the fact it is what it is, twitter was nice enough to generate something usable for you... the html file that is associated with this is around 150 lines long, the linked css file is just shy of 2500 lines.  Not to mention anything that happens inside the server before your link file was output to the user is a total unknown, unless you know one of the coders.

I tried swapping out some of the code with some bootstrap code, because that came from twitter, but as soon as it hit the server it ignored, the edited code, which I kind of expected.

I know this not what you probably wanted to hear, but I don't think there is really an easy answer for this one.